# Django load data to model

Tags: django

So usually in django you have an app let's say `common` you create and inside it can have a model lets say `Site` and you can dumpdata from the model like so `python manage.py dumpdata common.site > sites.json` and it works but this `python manage.py loaddata common.site < sites.json` doesn't work.

I'm curious if this is possible or not, if you know how to please share an example.

Comment: Yes you can do it, There is an example [here](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata). If you got any error, please show it.

Comment: Or, you can use fixtures, although they load the data every time the project reloads instead of only when you want.

Answer (score 1):

To load data to the table you just need to use:

```
python manage.py loaddata <filename>

python manage.py loaddata sites.json
```

Refer Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata

If the JSON is created using dumpdata the file already has the table name and app name no need to specify the app/model name along with the loaddata command.